# Курсор на консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Здравствуйте, как сделать обработку нажатия на определенный текст в консоли C#

Допустим

```
Console.WriteLine("Кнопка!");
```

как сделать курсор типа как FreePascal или в MsDos на C#. И обрабатывать нажатия на что либо

Comment: Скорее как Norton/Volcov Commander? На *nix это делается с помощью `ncurses`.

Comment: Можно-то всё, но поскольку это мало кому нужно, в официальную поставку это не вошло. Если поискать в nuget'е, найдётся, например, это: https://github.com/PhonicUK/CLRCLI. Гуглится ещё это: https://github.com/elw00d/consoleframework

Answer (score 0):

Никак. У меня тоже возникал такой вопрос когда-то. Я понял что ничего нет, создал форму, поместил PictureBox(Dock Fill) и выводил туда текст шрифтом System через Bitmap. Добавил обработчик Click и все заработало.